# SharePoint Learning Kit issues

Tags: error, learning-kit

I installed SharePoint Learning kit, version 1.5.2. I have some issues thou. When I'm accessing site with SLK as user which has Observer permissions, I'm getting this error in Assignment Web Part:

```
"To use the observor role session state must be enabled for the web application"
```

I followed instructions of user *observative* from codeplex discussion [here](http://slk.codeplex.com/discussions/208206), but unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.

I also haven't found any documentation on how I can assign children (learners) to parents (observers) to enable parents track their children assignments. Is there any tutorial/documentation/anything covering this topic?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have session state turned on in your web.config?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: That solved case with session state and observer role. Any ideas how one can set relationship between learners and observers?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I've only used an older version of the learning kit.